# Seam to CDI migration @Observes

Tags: cdi, seam

I am working on seam 2.1 to CDI migration. I need some help on migrating the following event into CDI.

```
@Observer(Identity.EVENT_POST_AUTHENTICATE)
public void addRoles() throws NamingException, SystemException {

BatchProcessor batchProcessor = (BatchProcessor)Component.getInstance("batchProcessor");
}
```

I am not sure how to handle the EVENT_POST_AUTHENTICATE in CDI.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this issue using picketlink. Picketlink contains the PostAuthenticateEvent. I have used that to resolve the issue,

```
public void addRoles(@Observes PostAuthenticateEvent event) throws NamingException, SystemException {
...
}
```

https://docs.jboss.org/picketlink/2/2.7.0.Final/api/org/picketlink/authentication/event/package-summary.html